# How to set the output in a differential amplifier?

Tags: sensors

Can anyone please tell me if the sensor output is 0 to +-10V, and I connect the sensor to a differential amplifier to get an output of 0 to 3.3V then what is the input voltage to the differential amplifier from -10v to +10v or (0 to 10 v or -10 to 0v)?

If I use -10 to 10 volts then the differential amplifier adds both the input voltages and gives +20V and with gain, we can adjust it to 0 to 3.3. But, if I use 0 to 10v or 0 to -10V then I get half voltage with the above set gain.

Can anyone please explain?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A differential amplifier amplifies the difference between the signals. If you had a differential amplifier that scales a ±10v differential signal to a 0 to 3.3v signal, it would expect that the maximum input would be a 20v difference between the terminals. That's why you need to apply a 20v signal to the input to get the output you want.

If you have a sensor that outputs from -10v to +10v then you would need to apply 10v to one side of your differential amplifier so that 0v from your sensor corresponds to 1.65v out, -10v is 0v and 10v is 3.3v